# How to create a recursive function that returns a copy of a single parameter (a list of strings), but with every character duplicated in each place?

Tags: string, list, function, recursion

Basically, I need to write a recursive function that takes a list of strings and then returns a list of strings with each character in each string repeated/doubled.

For example, doubleStringList(['I','love','overflow']) would return
['II','lloovvee','oovveerrffllooww'].

I decided to split it up into two recursive functions. I already made one function that returns the strings with doubled characters:

```
def doubleCharacter(seq):
    if len(seq) == 0:
        return seq
    else:
        return (seq[0] * 2) + doubleCharacter(seq[1:])
```

For example, entering doubleCharacter("overflow") would return   'oovveerrffllooww'

I'm trying to create a second recursive function that uses the first except for a list of strings as the paremeter rather than a single string. For example:

```
def doubleStringList(sList):
    if len(sList) == 0:
        return sList
    else:
        return doubleCharacter(sList[0]) + doubleStringList(sList[1:])
```

Theoretically, if I entered doubleStringList(["overflow","is","great"]), it should return ["oovveerrffllooww", "iiss", "ggrreeaatt"]. If someone could please help me figure out this code, I would appreciate it greatly.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. In the future, I urge you to give all relevant information. In this case the code was simple and easy to execute, but in general if you get an error message during your investigation into a problem, it is one of the first things that should be included into the question, right along with your code.

Comment: Please and language tag

Answer (score 0):

The error message gives a big clue:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

So, the last line should be

```
return [doubleCharacter(sList[0])] + doubleStringList(sList[1:])
```

Comment: wow I was literally sooo close! Sorry I forgot to include the error, but thank you so much!

Comment: Indeed, so close :)